# Overflow scroll won't work when div was created outside of the viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, transition

I'm building a full screen slider. The last slide is supposed to have a horizontal scrolling area. I'm using css translations (for a smoother animation) to bring the div inside of the viewport.

For some reason, the scrollbar won't work unless you resize the window.

My guess is that when the scrollable div is created outside of the viewport, it is not rendered by Chrome (for performance reasons?).

Then I guess when you resize, the whole thing gets calculated and redrawn and then it is taken into account.

Here is a JSFiddle that illustrates my problem.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/f3thbjqc/6/show/

Here's a video that illustrates my problem (when I wiggle the mouse is when I try to scroll right, unsuccessfully. Then I resize, and it starts working).

[image]

My setup: Mac os High Sierra. Both Chrome 69.0.3497.100, and Safari 11.0.1 (13604.3.5) behave the same, firefox doesn't have the bug somehow

Comment: it's working for me, without resizing

Comment: It works in jsFiddle, but not from the the jsshell.

Comment: weird... I'm on a macbook pro, using chrome 69, what is your setup?

Comment: And yeah, same for me, it works in jsFiddle, but not from jshell, which is full screen and replicates the bug in my app.

Comment: What is "the jsshell"?

Comment: You can see in the url, "jshell". Another way to view the fiddle is by this url: http://jsfiddle.net/f3thbjqc/6/ but for some reason, the bug isn't showing here

Comment: MacBook Pro using Safari 12. But same behavior in Chrome 71.

Comment: what do you mean "same behaviour"?

Comment: It scrolls for me, both in the fiddle and the jsshell. Same setup (Mac OS High Sierra, Chrome 69.0.3497.100). Are you expecting a scrollbar on the scrollable div?

Comment: I'm not expecting a scrollbar, chrome on OSX hides scrollbars by default. i'm only expecting the div to be scrollable... i'm gonna do a video to illustrate the bug

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with the materiallize framework when i was usings tabs and a slider inside. The problem was the slider was not working and after I resized the window it was working perfectly.

Try to fire this event manually when the slider is in view

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

Comment: Just tried, without success.. even if I set a timeout to wait for the animation to end, still no result. That's so weird.. how did you manage to fix your problem?

Comment: I set the timeout for mine to fire after 10ms and  it solved my problem. I know its not pretty but works. Did you try to setInterval to see if it even works?